# typo3 flux select multiple pages suggest wizard

Tags: select, typo3, flux

`<flux:field.input name="pages">
  <flux:wizard.link label="Select link" activeTab="pages" />
</flux:field.input>`

with this I can select ONE page. But how can I select MULTIPLE pages, like it is done at the Menu-Content-Items.

tryed: field.select -needs an item-propery. 
field.relation I did not succeed, too.

Thank you for your help,

Christian.

**Edit**: This is what I'm currently trying:

```
<flux:field.relation
    name="settings.relationtest"
    label="relationtest"
    multiple="true"
    size="6"
    minItems="0"
    maxItems="30"
    renderMode="singlebox"
    foreignTableField="pages" 
>
    <flux:wizard.suggest
        label="NULL"
        hideParent="0"
        pidDepth=""
        minimumCharacters="1"
        searchWholePhrase="0"
        table="pages"/>
</flux:field.relation>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, thus not an answer: I'd use a [relation field](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Field/RelationViewHelper.html), and a [suggest wizard](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Wizard/SuggestViewHelper.html) instead of the ones you used - what went wrong when trying that?

Comment: I am not sure about the parameters for the relation abs the wizard never finds anything... 
Do you have a working example?

Comment: <flux:field.relation name="settings.relationtest" label="relationtest" 
 multiple="true" size="6" minItems="0" maxItems="30" 
 renderMode="singlebox" 
 foreignTableField="pages" >
 <flux:wizard.suggest label="NULL"  hideParent="0"  pidDepth="" minimumCharacters="1" searchWholePhrase="0" table="pages" />
</flux:field.relation>

Comment: I've added that code into the question, so it is better readable. Hope I got it right. I can't answer your question though.

Comment: `<flux:field.relation name="settings.relationtest" label="relationtest" 
 multiple="true" size="6" minItems="0" maxItems="30" 
 renderMode="singlebox" 
 foreignTableField="pages" >
 <flux:wizard.suggest label="NULL"  hideParent="0"  pidDepth="" minimumCharacters="1" searchWholePhrase="0" table="pages" />
</flux:field.relation>`
Finds nothing. The ApacheLog says this:
`"POST /typo3/ajax.php?..."http://###element-tt_content-181`

Why tt_content?

Comment: confused aboute the comment function.....

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and tried a lot with different viewhelpers. [flux:field.relation](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Field/RelationViewHelper.html) seems the right solution for this one. I use a quite simple snippet:

```
<flux:field.relation label="Auswahl der Seiten" table="pages" size="6" multiple="true" minItems="0" maxItems="30" name="parentpages">
     <flux:wizard.suggest />
</flux:field.relation>
```

Selecting multiple pages works fine.

Perhaps your problem came from setting the 'table' parameter on flux.wizard.suggest ([Link](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/283)).